# Apple app rejection while google authentication (Metadata)

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, google-signin

I am using login with google in my app and getting user profile information from google.

I have tested and it is working fine at my end,but apple has rejected it.
I don't find any error at my end .

**Reason of rejection by apple: "Verify its you! device is not recognized", asking for verification**

I can access (login) and get all information using the same gmail id, As the demo account is created from india location 
But app reviewer from another country (USA) not able to login  "Verify its you! device is not recognized issue".

If anyone facing the same issue kindly guide how to fix this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that the only login method? Can you not simply provide them with basic email and password?

Comment: @Deepak kindly check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply create one Test Account separately with all security features off & without any 2 step authentication on to the account.

Try & test with the same account from 2-3 different devices just to make sure everything works correctly.

After that you can pass on that Test Account details to the Apple review team for the review purpose.

Hope it will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Apple can't test the app because they can't access the account you gave them because of the 2-Step Verification, so try to disable it from the account and give it to them again, you could follow these steps to achieve that. [Google support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by doing the following:

- Go to the Security settings of the Google account you provided to the Apple review team.
- Enable 2FA(if you haven't already).
- Add only the backup codes option. This includes:

  - Removing any mobile device that Google will use to send you the verification prompt.
  - Save you 8-digit codes to a safe place and copy them.
- Add the 8-digit codes to the notes section of your app version on AppStoreConnect. You can also reply to the review team in the resolution center with the codes, and re-submit the same build.

Remember the backup codes are single use.